# Outputting contents generated from loops into one column or list per loop

Tags: r

I am not a coder but I am trying to learn R while I process my data. I want to make a loop to go through each column and output the row names of the highest values in those columns (in order of highest value to lowest value). I specifically want to make a loop instead of doing it manually column-by-column because my dataset has a lot of columns and I really want to learn loops. Here is my example data:

```
mydata <- data.frame (rownames  = c("fifth", "second", "third", "first", "fourth"),
    value_1  = c(0,10,3,20,1),
    value_2 = c(10,20,13,30,11),
    value_3 = c(5,15,8,25,6)
    ) %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var="rownames")
```

For the output, I would love a table where each column has the row names in order of highest value to lowest value for each column in mydata. Alternately, even a separate "list" for each column would be fine.

example output as a table:

| value_1 | value_2 | value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first | first | first |
| second | second | second |
| third | third | third |
| fourth | fourth | fourth |

example output as "lists":

```
> value_1
[1] "first"  "second" "third"  "fourth" "fifth"  

> value_2
[1] "first"  "second" "third"  "fourth" "fifth"  

> value_3
[1] "first"  "second" "third"  "fourth" "fifth"
```

my attempt at a loop uses top_n(4, i) to return the row names of the highest 4 values in each column, but it doesn't put the row names in order of how high the value is. I tried to solve this by first sorting the rows by highest to lowest value with arrange(desc(i)).

```
> for (i in colnames(Sample_Ordering_Table)){
    data[,i] <- arrange(desc(i)) %>% rownames_to_column() %>% top_n(4, i) %>% pull(rowname)
    }
```

this resulted in the following error message
Error in UseMethod("arrange") :
no applicable method for 'arrange' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Even if the arrange did work, I don't know how to output the results of each loop to a separate column or value.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this can be done without a loop, it sounds like you'd like to fix your current loop solution.

The first argument of `arrange` is the data.frame, which is missing (often we pipe this in and don't think about it). You provide column names through `i` in your loop, but not `mydata`. So that should be added.

Second, `i` is a character value, not a symbol. So you can use the `.data` pronoun with `i` to access the column within `mydata`.

This example stores the result in a list.

```
lst <- list()

for (i in colnames(mydata)) {
  lst[[i]] <- mydata %>%
    arrange(desc(.data[[i]])) %>% 
    rownames_to_column() %>% 
    top_n(4, i) %>% 
    pull(rowname)
}
```

**Output**

```
$value_1
[1] "first"  "second" "third"  "fourth" "fifth" 

$value_2
[1] "first"  "second" "third"  "fourth" "fifth" 

$value_3
[1] "first"  "second" "third"  "fourth" "fifth"
```

Comment: 'top_n' is superseded by 'slice_max' in this context, so slice_max(i, n = 4) would achieve the same thing and be more robust

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation was thorough enough that I can actually understand how to do this now. I really appreciate you taking the time to explain everything.